# EJB 3.1 How to block external connection

Tags: java, jakarta-ee, jboss, ejb

I have a Stateless bean where I want to allow access only to the client that I authorize.

The bean:

```
@Stateless 
public class LibraryBean implements LibraryIFace { 

   @Override 
   public void setName(String name){ 
  sb.setName( name ); 
   } 

   @Override 
   public String getName(){ 
   return sb.getName(); 
   } 

   @EJB 
   private SingIFace sb; 

}
```

I know that anyone can access to this bean over the network.

How can I block all connections not trusted?

I using Wildfly.

Thanks in advance Andrea.

Comment: How do you want to identify whether a connection is trusted or not? Do you want to add Basic Auth?

Comment: With a token, or user and pass.

Comment: I'd recommend to separate your logic in the EJB from controlling external access. Do you really want to allow the client to directly access your EJB? It's more common to expose the EJB via e.g. REST and then do the authorization in that layer. And it's often better to use an existing security framework instead of trying to build this on your own.

Comment: @Geziefer Thanks for your response, No i don't want to check the permission to the EJB... I want that only my app can access to the EJB and not external application. of course I will check the permission of user into the client module compared to EJB.

Answer (score 1):

Check out the chapter [Securing EJBs](https://docs.jboss.org/author/display/WFLY8/Securing+EJBs) from the Wildfly documentation. It should help you to adjust access to your needs.

Comment: Thanks, So the connections check is delegated to the AS. Now, when I define @SecurityDomain("other") to EJB the client (in this case se servlet) must be authenticated? if yes, what must be done?

Comment: I don't want that the user do the login... I want use the security domain to block the direct access only to EJB module and not to the client of the EJB. I want that only MY app can access directly to the EJB.

Comment: @AndreaCatania: I wasn't in need to do this myself yet, so I'm not sure about the details. But concerning your environment - do you want to block access from other applications on the same server (if yes, why?) or do you want to block access from external clients (if yes, then just don't provide a remote interface).

Comment: I need to block the access to external clients but not to all. I don't think that all who use EJB "remote" allow access to everyone. hmmm

Comment: @AndreaCatania: I'm not aware if there is a special configuration for that case. But maybe you should then consider not providing a direct remote access to the EJB (which I would recommend anyway) and expose the functionality through a web service and restrict the access on that layer.